# Rails render in controller outside of action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

In the API I am building in rails, I've implemented some parameter checking and error handling in my base controller which the other controllers inherit from (to avoid duplicate code).

In my error handler function, I call `render` with the appropriate JSON return, status code etc...

However, rendering does not work as I am not calling render in the action itself. The action only calls the parameter checking function, which in turn calls the error handler if an error exists.

I tried using the RenderAnywhere gem, but that did not work (it's instructions do not contain Gemfile installation, and when trying to do that, it throws an error. I do not want to install a system-wide Gem).

What are other ways to render in a controller, but outside the action itself, without having to write redundant `render` calls in each action? Or is calling `render` in each action redundantly for errors the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean render outside of controllers or only action? If only outside of action did you tried `before/after_filter` ?

Comment: You want to render it in a model?

Comment: If you're referring to [render_anywhere](http://rubygems.org/gems/render_anywhere), its [README](https://github.com/yappbox/render_anywhere#usage) explains how to use it (including Gemfile instructions & simple usage examples).

Comment: Can you post the relevant controller and error handling code? I get what you're saying in general but its hard to answer the question without knowing the specifics. Off the bat though, if the error handling function is in a model, it sounds like you're better off returning something from the error handling function to the controller and rendering based on that.

Comment: how does it "call the error handler" a method call? what output does it give you?